# Как добавить/удалить класс элементам коллекции?

Tags: javascript, объекты, коллекции

Пытаюсь сделать галерею в которой есть карточки (картинка, название, ссылка) с пагинацией.
Информацию для карточек беру из массива объектов.

Нужно при клике на элемент с классом gallery__caption добавить ему класс gallery__caption--active, а при повторном клике удалить, но чтобы у других карточек не срабатывало добавление/удаление класса gallery__caption--active.

upd: Подправил вопрос.
upd new:

```
galleryCaption = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery__caption");
    galleryCaption.forEach((item) => {
      item.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        galleryCaption.forEach((el) => {
          el.classList.remove("gallery__caption--active");
          this.classList.add("gallery__caption--active");

          item.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.target.classList.remove("gallery__caption--active");
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

```js
const nextBtn = document.getElementById("btn_next");
const prevBtn = document.getElementById("btn_prev");

let current_page = 1;
let records_per_page = 3;

const objJson = [
  {
    imgLink: "../img/project-1.jpg",
    title: "example title1 ",
    btnLink: "https://test/example 1",
  },
  {
    imgLink: "../img/project-2.jpg",
    title: "example title 2",
    btnLink:
      "https://test/example 2",
  },
  {
    imgLink: "../img/project-3.jpg",
    title: "example title 3",
    btnLink:
      "https://test/example 3",
  },
  {
    imgLink: "../img/project-4.jpg",
    title: "example title 4",
    btnLink:
      "https://test/example 4",
  },
  {
    imgLink: "../img/project-5.jpg",
    title: "example title 5",
    btnLink:
      "https://test/example 5",
  },
  {
    imgLink: "../img/project-6.jpg",
    title: "example title 6",
    btnLink: "https://test/example 6",
  },
];

function prevPage() {
  if (current_page > 1) {
    current_page--;
    changePage(current_page);
  }
}

function nextPage() {
  if (current_page < numPages()) {
    current_page++;
    changePage(current_page);
  }
}

function changePage(page) {
  var galleryList = document.querySelector("ul.gallery__list");
  var page_span = document.getElementById("page");

  // Validate page
  if (page < 1) page = 1;
  if (page > numPages()) page = numPages();

  galleryList.innerHTML = "";

  for (
    var i = (page - 1) * records_per_page;
    i < page * records_per_page && i < objJson.length;
    i++
  ) {
    // Создаю элементы разметки
    const galleryItem = document.createElement("li");
    galleryItem.classList.add("gallery__item");
    galleryList.append(galleryItem);
    galleryItem.innerHTML += `<img loading="lazy" src="${objJson[i].imgLink}" alt="test">`;

    let galleryCaption = document.createElement("div");
    galleryCaption.classList.add("gallery__caption");
    galleryItem.append(galleryCaption);

    const galleryTitle = document.createElement("h3");
    galleryTitle.classList.add("gallery__title");
    galleryTitle.textContent = objJson[i].title;
    galleryCaption.append(galleryTitle);

    const galleryBottom = document.createElement("div");
    galleryBottom.classList.add("gallery__bottom");
    galleryCaption.append(galleryBottom);

    // неудачная попытка добавить gallery__caption--active к элементу с классом gallery__caption
    galleryCaption = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery__caption");

    galleryCaption.forEach((item) => {
      item.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.target.classList.remove("gallery__caption--active");
        this.classList.add("gallery__caption--active");
      });
    });

    const galleryBtnLink = document.createElement("a");
    galleryBtnLink.classList.add("gallery__link", "gallery-btn__item");
    galleryBtnLink.setAttribute("href", objJson[i].btnLink);
    galleryBtnLink.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    galleryBtnLink.textContent = "Open";
    galleryBottom.append(galleryBtnLink);
  }
  page_span.innerHTML = page + "/" + numPages();

  if (page == 1) {
    prevBtn.style.visibility = "hidden";
  } else {
    prevBtn.style.visibility = "visible";
  }

  if (page == numPages()) {
    nextBtn.style.visibility = "hidden";
  } else {
    nextBtn.style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  nextPage();
});

prevBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  prevPage();
});

function numPages() {
  return Math.ceil(objJson.length / records_per_page);
}

window.onload = function () {
  changePage(1);
};
```

```html
<ul class="list-reset gallery__list">

</ul>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="btn_prev">Prev</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="btn_next">Next</a>
page: <span id="page"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант...

```js
document.querySelector('.list-reset.gallery__list').addEventListener('click', e => {
  let o = e.target
  o = o.closest('.gallery__caption')
  if (o) o.classList.toggle('gallery__caption--active')
})

const nextBtn = document.getElementById("btn_next");
const prevBtn = document.getElementById("btn_prev");

let current_page = 1;
let records_per_page = 3;

const objJson = [{
    imgLink: "../img/project-1.jpg",
    title: "example title1 ",
    btnLink: "https://test/example 1",
  },
  {
    imgLink: "../img/project-2.jpg",
    title: "example title 2",
    btnLink: "https://test/example 2",
  },
  {
    imgLink: "../img/project-3.jpg",
    title: "example title 3",
    btnLink: "https://test/example 3",
  },
  {
    imgLink: "../img/project-4.jpg",
    title: "example title 4",
    btnLink: "https://test/example 4",
  },
  {
    imgLink: "../img/project-5.jpg",
    title: "example title 5",
    btnLink: "https://test/example 5",
  },
  {
    imgLink: "../img/project-6.jpg",
    title: "example title 6",
    btnLink: "https://test/example 6",
  },
];

function prevPage() {
  if (current_page > 1) {
    current_page--;
    changePage(current_page);
  }
}

function nextPage() {
  if (current_page < numPages()) {
    current_page++;
    changePage(current_page);
  }
}

function changePage(page) {
  var galleryList = document.querySelector("ul.gallery__list");
  var page_span = document.getElementById("page");

  // Validate page
  if (page < 1) page = 1;
  if (page > numPages()) page = numPages();

  galleryList.innerHTML = "";

  for (
    var i = (page - 1) * records_per_page; i < page * records_per_page && i < objJson.length; i++
  ) {
    // Создаю элементы разметки
    const galleryItem = document.createElement("li");
    galleryItem.classList.add("gallery__item");
    galleryList.append(galleryItem);
    galleryItem.innerHTML += `<img loading="lazy" src="${objJson[i].imgLink}" alt="test">`;

    let galleryCaption = document.createElement("div");
    galleryCaption.classList.add("gallery__caption");
    galleryItem.append(galleryCaption);

    const galleryTitle = document.createElement("h3");
    galleryTitle.classList.add("gallery__title");
    galleryTitle.textContent = objJson[i].title;
    galleryCaption.append(galleryTitle);

    const galleryBottom = document.createElement("div");
    galleryBottom.classList.add("gallery__bottom");
    galleryCaption.append(galleryBottom);

    const galleryBtnLink = document.createElement("a");
    galleryBtnLink.classList.add("gallery__link", "gallery-btn__item");
    galleryBtnLink.setAttribute("href", objJson[i].btnLink);
    galleryBtnLink.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    galleryBtnLink.textContent = "Open";
    galleryBottom.append(galleryBtnLink);
  }
  page_span.innerHTML = page + "/" + numPages();

  if (page == 1) {
    prevBtn.style.visibility = "hidden";
  } else {
    prevBtn.style.visibility = "visible";
  }

  if (page == numPages()) {
    nextBtn.style.visibility = "hidden";
  } else {
    nextBtn.style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  nextPage();
});

prevBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  prevPage();
});

function numPages() {
  return Math.ceil(objJson.length / records_per_page);
}

window.onload = function() {
  changePage(1);
};
```

```css
.gallery__caption--active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-reset gallery__list"></ul>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="btn_prev">Prev</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="btn_next">Next</a> page: <span id="page"></span>
```

Comment: А как сделать переключение toggle? Мне нужно, чтобы 1 раз нажал, применился класс, 2 раз нажал удалился, но только у той карточки, на которую жмёшь, у других чтобы не действовало...

Comment: Все верно. Вместо `add()` использовать `toggle()`.

Comment: Теперь получается, что gallery__title перекрывает gallery__caption, можно как то сделать, чтобы при нажатии на любые элементы внутри gallery_caption срабатывало переключение?

Comment: Проанализировать такое можно используя `o.closest('.gallery_caption')`...

Но кому тогда присваивать "активный" класс?

Comment: Без пагинации делал и без создания элементов в js, без проблем работает, нажимаю на любые элементы внутри gallery_caption и добавляется gallery_caption--active, а тут прям никак... не получается

Comment: Когда появляются новые элементы - на них нет событий... Придется на них еще раз вешать события или вешать событие на родительский элемент применяя "делегирование".
https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation

Comment: galleryCaption = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery__caption");

    galleryCaption.forEach((item) => {
      item.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        this.classList.toggle("gallery__caption--active");
      });
    }); Если так сделать, то работает с 1 карточкой и 3 карточкой, потом когда выбираю след 3, так же и с ними работает, почему со 2 карточкой не срабатывает?

Comment: Если посмотреть `galleryCaption.length` - сколько элементов будет показывать?

Comment: из-за пагинации я вообще не понимаю, как это работает galleryCaption.length в консоли выводится 3 значения 1, 2, 3

Comment: Если каждый раз у тебя 3 элемента - `forEach()` пройдет по всем... Можно еще посмотреть все элементы, на которые идет навешивание событий - `console.log(item)`...

Comment: Обновил в посте, вроде работает, но правильно ли это... Как то ещё надо, чтобы работало и по клику на gallery__title и gallery__bottom

Comment: Это все дети `gallery__caption` - от них можно выйти на общего родителя и работать с ним.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!